# Creating legend for graph with multiple lines representing a 'group'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph

From a dataframe in pandas 'g' I have the following data:

```
index    Speaker          Date        ARI     Flesch    Kincaid  
0        Alan Greenspan   1996  15.234878  34.669383  14.533217   
1        Alan Greenspan   1997  16.235605  31.415163  15.335869    
11       Alan S. Blinder  2002  14.299481  41.847836  13.681203         
12       Alan S. Blinder  2003        NaN        NaN        NaN     
14       Alice M. Rivlin  1996  15.828971  33.394999  15.211662
```

With the code below I have been able to produce the following graph:

```
s = data
s['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(s['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
s = s.set_index(['Date'])
grouped = s.groupby('Speaker').resample('AS').mean()
grouped = grouped.reset_index()
g = grouped.reset_index()
g["Date"] = g["Date"].dt.year
g.plot(x='Date', y='Flesch', colormap = cm.cubehelix, legend=True, 
title="Auto", figsize=(12,10))
```

[image: My current graph]

I would like the graph to include different colors for each line and place a legend that notes which "Speaker" is associated with each line. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: My current thought is to make a pivot table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try something like this:

```
df.pivot_table(values='Flesch',index='Date',columns='Speaker').reset_index().plot(x='Date',colormap= cm.cubehelix)
```

[image]

(I just added that marker to show those single points in your test data.)

Comment: Yup, that does it -- thanks! One follow up question: how do you move the location of the legend? (I can also google it :p) Thanks again!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348183/pandas-bar-plot-with-specific-colors-and-legend-location?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: Thanks, I'm still working on it but this is really helpful :)

Comment: Got it now! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Try to `groupby` by speaker and then plot as described [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.plot.html)

Comment: That creates an individual graph for each 'Speaker'... I already passed a groupby argument in line 4 of my code...the main problem is getting the different colors and a legend containing the speaker's name...thanks

Comment: Yes, thats adds a level of comlexity to your graph. Personally I would prefer to use seaborn, as shown [here](http://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/timeseries_from_dataframe.html) but I'll be happy to see a built in elegant pandas solution as well

Comment: Seaborn is a great package.  You don't need to do the data manipulate as you do with pandas plot.